# Spring batch JdbcPagingItemReader endless loop

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am facing problems with JdbcPagingItemReader. I am stucked in endless loop. I read about that [itemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) contract **have to return null**, but I don't manage to implement it correctly. Somebody can show me an example?

```
public List<TransactionDTO> getTransactions(Integer chunk, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate)
            throws Exception {

        final TransactionMapper transactionMapper = new TransactionMapper();

        final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause(env.getProperty("sql.fromdates.select"));
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause(env.getProperty("sql.fromdates.from"));
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause(env.getProperty("sql.fromdates.where"));
        sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey(env.getProperty("sql.fromdates.sort"));

        final Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("startDate", startDate);
        parametros.put("endDate", endDate);

        final JdbcPagingItemReader<TransactionDTO> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setQueryProvider(sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject());
        // TODO esto debe ser el chunk
        itemReader.setPageSize(1);
        itemReader.setFetchSize(1);
        itemReader.setRowMapper(transactionMapper);
        itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
        itemReader.setParameterValues(parametros);

        ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
        itemReader.open(executionContext);
        List<TransactionDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();

        TransactionDTO primerDto = itemReader.read();
        while (primerDto != null) {
            list.add(itemReader.read());
        }
        itemReader.close();

        return list;

    }
```

Comment: You never get out of the while loop. The `primerDto` is never reassigned. Also what has this to do with Spring Batch? You are using a component but next to that don't do anything with Spring Batch. Why even bother using the `JdbcPagingItemReader` if you aren't using it from a chunk based step? Looks like you are working around Spring Batch instead of using it.

Comment: Oops, I was really convinced about that I was making bad use of ItemReader interface :S. I have to rewrite some code to truly use spring batch. Thanks